# How to handle exceptions using events in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony4

Right now I'm trying to catch an exception event like that:

```
try {
    echo 1 / 0;
} catch (\Exception $e){
    $subs = new ExceptionSubscriber();
    $this->dispatcher->addSubscriber($subs);
};
```

I have defined ExceptionSubscriber which looks as follows:

```
class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['processException', 10],
                ['exception', -10],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function exception(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        echo 'test321';
    }

    public function processException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        echo 'test123';
    }
}
```

And this is my services.yaml

```
App\EventSubscriber\ExceptionSubscriber:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: kernel.exception }
```

I understand that regular PHP exception I'm catching is not one of the kernel exception events, in that case I have to create custom exception event, right?

The way I'm dispatching events using `EventSubscriber`, not listener is good

Do I have to dispatch those events or they are passed into subscriber in some magical way?

Comment: Sorry I just sat back to that I had enough :P
Yeah I saw those questions I'm still feeling lost, right now I'm somehow trying to cause kernel exception, don't really know how just yet but Im fighting ;)

Comment: I did cause a fatal error by calling a method that doesn't exist, I'm thinking how I could return something else than a symfony standard 500 error page

Comment: Okay, now I got it, for me, entry point was a console, after switching kernel exceptions into console errors now it seems to be working!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an `Exception` is thrown (and it is not handled), the `HttpKernel` catches it and dispatches a `kernel.exception` event.

But in your example this would never happen, since you are catching the exception yourself. And are trying to create a subscriber there, which doesn't make a lot of sense; if anything you would be dispatching an event. But dispatching a new event is not necessary, since the `kernel.exception` event is already dispatched by the framework.

If you want to catch that event, you need to create your own Event Listener. A basic example:

```
class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        // inspect the exception
        // do whatever else you want, logging, modify the response, etc, etc
    }
}
```

You would need to configure this class to actually listen to these events:

```
services:
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

There is nothing else to be done. Any uncaught exception will go through here. No need to create specific `try/catch` blocks (although they are a good idea in general terms, since handling your own exceptions is generally a good thing).

This is all explained in the docs in these places, among others:

- [Working with the kernel.exception Event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event)
- [Creating an Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener)

Comment: Subscribers are better than listeners: no configuration to write, subscribed events directly in the code, ...

Comment: That's mostly a matter of preference. Personally, I prefer listeners explicitly configured and have listeners with just one task.

Comment: I guess it is. I shouldn't have been so strict. Maybe this article could change your mind :p https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/05/16/don-t-ever-use-listeners/

Comment: I was already familiar with that article. I happen to disagree with many of the points it makes.

Answer (score 1):

Uncatched exceptions in controllers are catched by symfony which then constructs and dispatches the kernels exception event.
Actually you are not catching any exceptions, you are subscribing to an event. Symfony catches them and you receive an event with a method `getException`.
You can find more infos here: [Symfony: How to Customize Error Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: Hm okay so I do subscribe to the event that is automatically dispatched, Im doing that in kernel by adding  `$container->register('subscriber_service_id', ExceptionSubscriber::class)
            ->addTag('kernel.event_subscriber');`

Comment: What I should do to catch an exception for example from a service?

Comment: @Maarduk Symfony is still php, to catch an exception just use the regular `try-catch` block,
Only if *you* dont catch the exception explicitly, symfony will catch it and then dispatch the event. For the config it depends on your env. If you are using the framework bundle and have autowiring enabled, Symfony will take any service automatically that implements `EventSubscriberInterface` and register it as a subscriber. Without autowiring you have to tag it manually.