# How do I send a JSON response within Symfny error handling?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, error-handling

Im building a Rest API with Symfon. Im having trouble with returning a JSON String in case of for instance an 404 exception. I have already read the symfony docs on these topics:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

And tried it with an individual  event Listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();
        $message = sprintf(
            'My Error says: %s with code: %s',
            $exception->getMessage(),
            $exception->getCode()
        );

        echo "error happened";

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($message);

        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

       
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse($this->translator->trans('not_found')));

        return new JsonResponse($this->translator->trans('not_found'));
    }
}
```

And I registered my exception Lister the following way in services.yaml

```
parameters:

services:
  App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Still Im getting the normal 404 html template.

What am I missing here?

I also looked in the following threads but that doesn’t help as well:

[Symfony 5 custom 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202595/symfony-5-custom-404-page)

[How to handle exceptions using events in Symfony 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572597/how-to-handle-exceptions-using-events-in-symfony-4)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot 2 more things :

- implements EventSubscriberInterface
- getSubscribedEvents function

so your class will be somthing like this :

```
class ExceptionEventHandler implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException'];
    }
}
```

If nothing happen try clean the cache...

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it without introducing new classes.
First, you have to have Serializer installed:

```
composer require symfony/serializer-pack
```

Then, in your `services.yaml`:

```
services:
    error_renderer:
        class: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorRenderer\SerializerErrorRenderer
        arguments:
            $format: 'json'
```

This way, all built-in errors like 404 and so will be returned as JSON by default:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
    "title": "An error occurred",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "Not Found"
}
```